# Substrate , private network : Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F

Tags: substrate-node-template

when i study    05-private-network
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/blob/main/v3/tutorials/05-private-network/index.mdx

success : node01

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name node01 \
--rpc-cors all
```

when i start node02 in another PC
Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Timeout }

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9946 \
--rpc-port 9934 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--name node02 \
--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWRsvHgi52m6jfcQ9vi7323NsfPmBUU4YA7RoQWz7ec6AT \
--password-interactive \
--rpc-cors all
```

```
2022-06-22 15:04:18 Substrate Node    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-681a9d8e3e8    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2022    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Chain specification: Local Testnet    
2022-06-22 15:04:18   Node name: node02    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Role: AUTHORITY    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/node02/chains/local_testnet/db/full    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs    
2022-06-22 15:04:18   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWAhV7Hcji9w59rNyhaY3rKufNJczWrazsTYj6haTwDTAG    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Operating system: linux    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  CPU architecture: x86_64    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Target environment: gnu    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  CPU cores: 2    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Memory: 4550MB    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Kernel: 5.14.0-109.el9.x86_64    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Linux distribution: CentOS Stream 9    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Virtual machine: yes    
2022-06-22 15:04:18  Highest known block at #0    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9934, allowed origins=None    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9946, allowed origins=None    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 creating instance on iface 192.168.31.22    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 discovered: 12D3KooWRsvHgi52m6jfcQ9vi7323NsfPmBUU4YA7RoQWz7ec6AT /ip4/192.168.31.5/tcp/30333    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 discovered: 12D3KooWRsvHgi52m6jfcQ9vi7323NsfPmBUU4YA7RoQWz7ec6AT /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 discovered: 12D3KooWRsvHgi52m6jfcQ9vi7323NsfPmBUU4YA7RoQWz7ec6AT /ip6/::1/tcp/30333    
2022-06-22 15:04:18 discovered: 12D3KooWRsvHgi52m6jfcQ9vi7323NsfPmBUU4YA7RoQWz7ec6AT /ip6/fe80::feaa:14ff:fe04:f3fb/tcp/30333    
2022-06-22 15:04:23  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), finalized #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), ⬇ 0.4kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-06-22 15:04:28  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), finalized #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.2kiB/s    
2022-06-22 15:04:33  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), finalized #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-06-22 15:04:38  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), finalized #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), ⬇ 58 B/s ⬆ 57 B/s    
2022-06-22 15:04:38 ❌ Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Timeout }    
2022-06-22 15:04:43  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), finalized #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-06-22 15:04:48  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), finalized #0 (0x1fa9…6a05), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is a `Timeout` error. Are you connected to the internet, on vpn, or anything that could be impeding your from communicating with the outside world e.g. https://telemetry.polkadot.io

Comment: This is discussed & closed [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-telemetry/issues/471) coz of not being reproduce-able . It happens to me from only when starting the first test node for the first time fwiw.

Comment: i get the error `Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Timeout }` when i run the command in the "Run Cargo Contract Node" section of the README of https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTest with commit d7c8a98 where i run `substrate-contracts-node` and pass the option `--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0"`. it should be reproducable since it uses specific versions with docker